# Как разрешить конфликт двух JDK?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

При компиляции у меня все время падает такое предупреждение:

> objc[41742]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x108cdb4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x108da94e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

И хотя компиляция проходит эта ошибка получается при первом запуске.

Как избавится от этой проблемы? Если я правильно понимаю то происходит конфликт версий JDK. Поправьте меня если нет. Причем это появилось когда я поставил `intellij IDEA 2017.2` до этого стояла версия `2016.2` и такого не было.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43003012/5812238

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Перевод ответа [@CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003231/5812238)</sub>

---

**TL;DR** сообщение безвредно, чтобы убрать его надо обновить Java до версии 9 или 8u152

---

Описание в трекере ошибок Intellij:

- [IDEA-170117](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170117) "objc: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both ..." warning in Run consoles

Это [старая ошибка в Java](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8022291) для Mac, которая [возникает из-за Java Agent](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/4fde1be3df5f7c145f943a969eb261e32bf72ef6), используемого IDE при старте приложения. Это сообщение безвредно и его можно спокойно игнорировать. Комментарий разработчиков Oracle:

> The message is benign, there is no negative impact from this problem since both copies of that class are identical (compiled from the exact same source). It is purely a cosmetic issue.

> Сообщение безвредно, от него не будет никаких негативных последствий, так как обе копии класса идентичны (они скомпилированы из одинаковых исходников). Это чисто косметическая проблема.

Ошибка [исправлена](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8022291) в Java 9 и в [Java 8 update 152](http://jdk.java.net/8/).

**Таким образом, решением будет обновить Java до версии 9 или 8u152.**

---

Если вариант с обновлением Java не подходит, и ошибка раздражает или как-то влияет на ваши приложения (хотя не должна), то временным решением может быть отключение `idea_rt` launcher agent с помощью добавления `idea.no.launcher=true` в `idea.properties`. (`Help` | `Edit Custom Properties...`). После этого нужно перезапустить Intellij.

Однако **не рекомендуется** отключать IntelliJ IDEA launcher agent. Он используется для мягкого завершения работы, дампов потоков, участвует в решение проблемы с слишком длинными строками (превышающими лимит OS) и т.д. Вероятно не стоит терять эти возможности ради избавления от безвредного сообщения.